# Is it impossible to hid options of a combobox with php?

Tags: php, html, combobox

Using a switch in php, i want to hide the options of a combobox based on the value that has been pre-selected from the database. I've been told to do this through a php switch statement, and here's what i got:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                <select name="cbostatus" id="cbostatus">
                <option selected "" ></option>
                <option value="1" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Planned') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Planned</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Started') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Started</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Available') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Available</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Impeded') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Impeded</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Concluded') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Finished</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
```

That was the combo, and here's the switch:

```
                <?php
                switch ($row['task_status'])
                {               
                    case 'Planned':
                        echo '
                            <script>
                                    cbostatus.options[4].style.display = "none"; 
                                    cbostatus.options[5].style.display = "none"; 
                                    cbostatus.options[3].style.display = "none"; 
                            </script>
                        ';
                        break;

                    case 'Available':
                        echo '
                            <script>
                                    cbostatus.options[1].style.display = "none"; 
                                    cbostatus.options[4].style.display = "none"; 
                                    cbostatus.options[5].style.display = "none"; 
                            </script>
                        ';
                        break;

                    case 'Started':
                        echo '
                            <script>
                                    cbostatus.options[1].style.display = "none"; 
                            </script>
                        ';
                        break;

                    case 'Impeded':
                        echo '
                            <script>
                                    cbostatus.options[1].style.display = "none"; 
                            </script>
                        ';
                        break;  

                    case 'Concluded':
                        echo '
                            <script>
                                    cbostatus.options[1].style.display = "none"; 
                            </script>
                        ';
                        break;  

                }
                ?>
```

But that doesn't work. Why? Is it impossible? I've been trying to do this for three days now. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: where/how is this JS running? if you're putting it into the page BEFORE the actual form element, then the js won't find anything because that part of the page hasn't been parsed yet.

Comment: oh god, thank you so so so much, you have no idea how grateful i am, thank you

Comment: have you assigned `cbostatus` before? (with `document.getElementById` f.e.)

Comment: and wouldn't it be much easier to not show it (via php) in first place? This way you produce a lot of redundant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the switch is the best way to do it, and I would forgo the JavaScript and do it all with PHP. This way you won't have to worry about hiding options, because only the ones you need will be there to begin with. My suggestion is this instead:

Define an array of numeric values and visible options for each status:

```
$status = [
    'Planned'   => ['val' => 1, 'options' => ['Planned','Started']],
    'Started'   => ['val' => 2, 'options' => ['Started','Available','Impeded','Concluded']],
    'Available' => ['val' => 3, 'options' => ['Started','Available']],
    'Impeded'   => ['val' => 4, 'options' => ['Started','Available','Impeded','Concluded']],
    'Concluded' => ['val' => 5, 'options' => ['Started','Available','Impeded','Concluded']],
];
```

Then output your select options based on the task status like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="cbostatus" id="cbostatus">
        <option selected "" ></option>
        <?php  foreach ($status[$row['task_status']]['options'] as $option) {
            $selected = $row['task_status'] == $option ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo '<option value="'. $status[$option]['val'] .'">'. $option .'</option>';
        } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```